# how to configure the magento 2 social login extension

Tags: php, magento2

I downloaded a free magento2 extension from [this website](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-social-login-extension/). I added it to my localhost project. I pasted the `app` folder to the root directory, and ran the command  `magento setup:upgrade` but in the admin panel, the Configuration page of "social login' is empty
[image: see screenshot]

The frontend page displays an error:

[image: see screenshot]

`a:4:{i:0;s:37:"Object DOMDocument should be created.";i:1;s:12153:"#0 /opt/lampp/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/Reader.php(95): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger->getDom()`

anybody knows how to resolve the questions ? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete `di` and `genernation` folder

```
rm -rf var/di* 
rm -rf var/generation/*
```

After that deploy static content

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I got the same error. I download latest version and run above command. It is working now